# Powerapps "add picture" and image controls file content-type header validation

Tags: image, validation, content-type, powerapps

Powerapps "add picture" and image controls restrict the accepted file types to image files (e.g. jpeg, gif), it does allow uploading other file types, including executable files. However, by changing an executable file's extension e.g. to jpg, you will be able to upload it via the "add picture" and image controls as it does not validate the file content ("Content-Type" Header validation). Is there a way to implement the file content validation to ensure that only valid image files are accepted?

Answer (score 1):

On the OnChange of your AddMediaButton1 that's automatically generated, paste:

```
Set(
  ImageFile, 
  JSON( 
    UploadedImage1.Image, 
    JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData 
  )
)
```

If you look at the text it generates once you change the media, it shows the output type. From this string of text, you can validate what media is uploaded and take actions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had tried tried that earlier. The result is based on file extension. If I have 2 files (File1.jpg and File2.exe) then I rename File2.exe to File2Exe.jpg (note I have changed the file extension) and I upload both files, the result of the JSON function will be the same. My issue is to check beyond the file extension. I need to determine from the file contents if the file is a valid image file has been uploaded.

Comment: I created a flow, passed the base64 data to that flow, and did a base64decode action. For a specific image i get the Adobe information back that states it's <dc:format>image/png</dc:format>

So you can use the Base64Decode/Base64ToBinary functions to check some stuff on the input, and validate back to PowerApps, or you can use an external API that checks the MIME type of the base64 content, instead of the extension. But more advanced stuff no, PowerApps doesn't have that out of the box sadly.